# Exercise 1(a), Section 3.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $F$ a field. Let $W$ be the set of all vectors $(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n$ such that $x_1+…+x_n=0_F$.
>
> (a) Prove that $W^0$ consist of all linear functional $f$ of the form $f((x_1,…,x_n))=c\cdot \sum_{j=1}^nx_j$.

**My attempt:** $W=\{(x_1,…,x_n)\in F^n|x_1+…+x_n=0_F\}$. Let $f\in W^0\leq (F^n)^*$. Then $f\in (F^n)^*$$=L(F^n,F)$ such that $f(\alpha)=0_F$, $\forall \alpha \in W$. Suppose $\{e_1,…,e_n\}$ is standard basis of $F^n$. It’s easy to check $e_1,…,e_n\notin W$. Let $y=(y_1,…,y_n)\in F^n$. Then $f(y)$ $=f(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\cdot e_i)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\cdot f(e_i)$. We claim $f(e_i)=f(e_{i+1})$, $\forall i\in J_{n-1}$. Fix $i\in J_{n-1}$. Let $z=(z_1,…,z_n)$ such that $z_i=1_F$,  $z_{i+1}=-1_F$ and $z_j=0_F$, if $j\neq i,i+1$. So $z\in W$. Then $f(z)$ $=\sum_{j=1}^nz_j\cdot f(e_j)$ $=z_i\cdot f(e_i)+z_{i+1}\cdot f(e_{i+1})$ $=f(e_i)-f(e_{i+1})$ $=0_F$. So $f(e_i)=f(e_{i+1})$. Since $i$ was arbitrary, $f(e_i)=f(e_{i+1})$, $\forall i\in J_{n-1}$. Thus $f(e_i)=c$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Hence $f(y)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\cdot f(e_i)$ $= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\cdot c$ $=c\cdot (\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)$, $\forall y\in F^n$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: It looks correct, although I prefer  different exposition, applying the same idea. Let $f$ be a linear functional. Then $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)=a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\ldots +a_nx_n$ for some coefficients $a_i\in F,$ namely $a_i=f(e_i).$ Assume $f$ vanishes on $W.$ Observe that  $e_1-e_i\in W$ for $i=2,3,\ldots, n.$ Thus $0=f(e_1-e_i)=a_1-a_i.$ Therefore $\alpha_i=\alpha_1$ for any $i.$ Hence $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)=\alpha_1(x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_n).$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yup. Your proof is compact and precise.